# Is shared_ptr always free memory automatically?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

You are partially replacing old code from the past. I'm replacing an existing pointer with a smart pointer for this operation, and I'm curious about deallocation. I replaced the code as below, will a leak occur?

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Interface>> interface_list;

for (int i = 0 ; i < 5; ++i) {
  Interface *buffer = CreateFactory(i);
  if (buffer) interface_list.emplace_back(buffer);
}
...
for (std::shared_ptr<Interface> it: interface_list) {
  it.reset();
}
//IS iT ok?
```

Comment: No leak will occurs but `it.reset()` will deallocate a copy, `interface_list` still contains valid pointers, is that what you want? What are you trying to do?

Comment: `shared_ptr` will automatically free the memory once the ref-count drops to 0.

Comment: You are creating a copy that is only available within the loop. Reseting it does not reset the original pointer.

Comment: smart pointers do not make your code automagically leak free. They do help a lot to reason about ownership and enable you to write clean code that has no leaks, but there is no fool proof guarantee. That being said, the incomplete fragment of code is insufficient to say it is free of leaks or not

Comment: This could leak if `emplace_back` throws. You can store `scanner_buffer` in an intermediate `unique_ptr` to avoid this.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: nah... the question was weird. I wonder if the same result as when doing a delete comes out when I reset it.

Comment: this is legacy code. Is it the same behavior?
    if (interface) { delete interface; interface = nullptr; }

Comment: I know that it is automatically deleted, but this deletion is a code used to arbitrarily stop a thread. I want to free memory immediately.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you fix the loop to call `reset` on the actual `shared_ptr`s instead of copies, the answer is "yes":

```
for (auto& it: interface_list) {
  it.reset();
}
```

That leaves you with a list of dummy `shared_ptr` instances, of course.
You can also just clear the vector and have C++ reset the pointers for you:

```
interface_list.clear();
```

or just let `interface_list` go out of scope.